# Git file locally marked as deleted after pull

Tags: git, azure-devops, continuous-integration

An issue started today where one of our branches is acting very weird.
If the branch is pulled a file is marked for, and is, deleted, as an unstaged change. Comparing with the server version of the branch this file definitely exists.

If I do git checkout on the file, the deletion is undone, of course.
If I further remove the local version of this branch and do another pull, the same file is NOT marked for deletion.

The latest change to this file was well over three months ago. The latest commit a few days ago. Nightly CI-pipelines have been running fine.

We are using Azure DevOps and all included features such as build pipelines using multiple agents, et.c., et.c.

Any clues?

I should add this is causing huge problems as our builds can no longer run as of today. Because the build steps pull the branch -> gets the same marked for deletion -> building the solution fails.

**The following happens, checkout from a completely clean, unrelated with no changes:**

```
git checkout <corrupt branch>
git status
```

[image: after git pull]

We get the same result if we pull the branch before or after checkout, locals where the corrupt branch is not already completely in sync.

**Edit, we noticed:**

warning: the following paths have collided (e.g. case-sensitive paths
on a case-insensitive filesystem) and only one from the same
colliding group is in the working tree:

*<lowercasefolder/.../>*

*<CamelCaseFolder/.../>*

No change has been made to the folder path or file. This path is used by hundreds of projects. Only one of them think the path has been duplicated.
Any ideas?

Comment: Can you add some command- / git status output to your question? It could be helpful.

Comment: Something that comes to mind, that has happened to me, is `--autostash` but i'm guessing you've tried this enough to rule that out.  `--autostash` can stash and restore your stash sorrounding a pull (which can not be done with local modifications). This includes restoring a deletion. And `--autostash` can be configured to always happen during pulls.

Comment: It happens on every machine this branch is pulled to. Multiple workstations and more importantly fresh VMs and Containers with no shared local settings. We haven't changed anything in the build in a long time. This happened over night.

Comment: According to your error message, you are using a case-insensitive filesystem. Which operating system are you using?

Comment: We solved it. It is stupid.
We're using windows. The problem was indeed the case insensitivity. The biggest problem was the fact that no history was shown of this path ever changing. It was obvious something has changed.

It turns out one of our developers had moved exactly this file to a lowercase path.
In a branch/build that was unrelated to where the problem showed itself.

It showed some problems with having a leaky build and dirty workspace we have now corrected. We have also turned off the ability to commit changes in path which only differ in case. Luckily it was fairly isolated.

Comment: @gwow12345 Glad to hear you solved this problem. Would you please [mark your answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235)? This will make it easier for people who have the same question to find answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was indeed the case insensitivity. The biggest problem was the fact that no history was shown of this path ever changing. It was obvious something has changed.

It turns out one of our developers had moved exactly this file to a lowercase path. In a branch/build that was unrelated to where the problem showed itself.

It showed some problems with having a leaky build and dirty workspace in an isolated agent pool we have now corrected. We have also turned off the ability to commit changes in path which only differ in case. Luckily it was fairly isolated.

It feels stupid after having found the solution..
You live and you learn.